# Handwriting widget for iBooks Author

Tags: ibooks

I am looking for a widget (HTML5, Dashcode, Javascript, whatever) that will allow the user of a textbook published from iBooks Author to use their finger or stylus to hand write notes within the textbook itself.  I am not sure if it is even possible.

Many students like taking handwritten notes while reading and this functionality would be awesome.  The comment note is nice but I have had students say they earn better when actually writing the information.

Comment: stackoverflow is a programming questions website. You seem to be looking for a program that is already written.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to embed and adapt this [finger painting demo](http://toc.oreilly.com/2011/11/html5-for-publishers-canvas.html) ([live example](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920022473/blob/master/finger_painting/finger_painting.html)) in javascript within an HTML widget. Or any equivalent 'touch drawing' code.

However I would really recommend to not even try to implement this as solutions like [swipe](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swipe-type-for-ipad/id486383126?mt=8) make typing on devices about as fast as handwriting.